# start mobile gis with android

Tags: android, gis, openlayers-3

I want to make gis android apps . I've worked with webgis open source services like geoserver and openlayers . So i've worked with server side programming language like php. Now i do not have any information about android programming.I need that to make my webgis project in mobile versions. what are the steps for me?

Comment: Step **#1**: Google. Step **#2**: See Step **#1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Cordova project (https://cordova.apache.org/) to create mobile apps with HTML, CSS & JS. It work fine with OL3.
The idea is to encapsulate the html page in a webview on the device, so the code can be run cross platform (Android, iOS, etc).

Comment: I installed cordova on my system and i created a non-gis application but when I try to create an app with openlayers3 it dosn't work,can someone help me?